# Ads stopped working after a year when app is build from newer version of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

About a year ago i finished a super simple game in android studio and published it. Now i wanted to make a small update and show ads on more proper place. But ads won't work at all - code is the same as it was, but ads just won't load.

My account is not disabled since if I download my game from playstore ads still work.

I use different version of android studio, so the project upgraded itself, but I don't know if it changed graddle or manifest or something so this could happen.

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded () {
            if(enableAd) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **onAdClosed()** in your AdListener to reload your ad each time is has been displayed, and create your initial Ad as part of the **mainActivity.create()**.

Use **mInterstitialAd.show()** anywhere in your app when you want to show the ad. After it is shown, it closes and will reload the next ad.

What this does is buffers your Ad. Whenever you show the interstitial ad, it shows the one that is already loaded, then reloads a new one after you've shown the ad. Makes for a quicker ad.show().

```
mInterstatialAd = new InterstitialAd(getBaseContext());
  mInterstatialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources()
                  .getString(R.string.AdmobTestInterstitial));
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed () {
        mInterstatialAd.loadAd(myAdRequest);
    }
});
public void showMyInterstitialAd(){
    if(mInterstitialAd!=null &&
       mInstitialAd.isLoaded()) mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

good luck.

Comment: Hi, that is almost excatly the "update" i wanted to make, but ads won't show at all now, not even aftor long time. So thank you for this suggestion and I will probably implement it, but that doesnt solve my problem yet.

Comment: have you  tried it with the Google AdMob test accounts?

Comment: Upon further investigation i found out i get this errorCode 

public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

But I get it always, and when i download app from store it shows normally.

Comment: can you post the logcat with this error code? if it's a 3 then your ads are working fine but there is an issue with your account.

A quick check would be substitute your id, with the test id's.

**
 <string name="AdmobTestAppID">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>
    <string name="AdmobTestBannerID">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
    <string name="AdmobTestInterstitial">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>
    <string name="AdmobTestReward">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917</string>
**

Comment: test ads dont work as well, but they dont return error 3

EDIT: banner works, intersital no

Comment: I dunno, I literally did the same in another activity and that works. but I can update my app now so thank you for your help. Not sure whether to accept this answer since it doesn't answer the original question, but original question was something really unexplainable anyway